# something like gap axis

Tags: graphics

If we have two financial graphics like EPAM and IBM. How we can do this?[image] Sorry, for my English.I think, you understand me

Comment: Have a look here [Financial Visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FinancialVisualization.html) and here [Financial & Economic Data](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FinancialAndEconomicData.html)

Comment: Please add more detail to this question. At the moment it is unclear what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
 c1 =
  CandlestickChart[{"IBM", {{2015, 1, 20}, {2015, 11, 9}}},
  ChartLegends -> "IBM",
  Frame -> {False, True, True, True},
  ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {10, 10}},
  ImageSize -> Medium];

c2 =
 CandlestickChart[{"BOE", {{2015, 1, 20}, {2015, 11, 9}}},
  ChartLegends -> "BOE",
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
  ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {10, 10}},
  ImageSize -> Medium];

Grid[{{c1}, {c2}}, Spacings -> {0, -3.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good idea, but i want to do it without removal two pictures.